# How can I change the Content Background Color of a TabPanel (TabView) in Primereact (JS)?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, primereact

How can I change the Content Background Color of a TabPanel (TabView) in Primereact (JS) ? Ideally to the basic background color of the page, which is black here (I guess). I think I have to modify css, or, maybe add some attribute in a style="..." way, but I am not familiar at all when it comes to styling (Sorry).

Appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

https://primereact.org/tabview/

[image]

Comment: You are not using PrimeFaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS.

```css
.p-tabview-panel {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Change to any color you want.

[image]